ASP.NET Framework - Publish Failure because it is being used by another process
I have this ASP.NET Framework-4.8 project called:
MyOTPWebService

It resides in:
C:\Mypath\My_Projects\MyTiger

which is:
C:\Mypath\My_Projects\ProjectTiger\MyWebService

It builds fine, but when I tried to publish into:
C:\Users\myapp\Desktop\My_Deployments\MyOtp

I got this error:

Publish has encountered an error.
Error     Copying file .vs\My_WebService\FileContentIndex\f74e8642-dd7b-4a97-a9ef-86760105c3db.vsidx to C:\Users\myapp\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\MyWebService--676085791\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp.vs\My_WebService\FileContentIndex\f74e8642-dd7b-4a97-a9ef-86760105c3db.vsidx failed. The process cannot access the file '.vs\My_WebService\FileContentIndex\f74e8642-dd7b-4a97-a9ef-86760105c3db.vsidx' because it is being used by another process.

It is in Visual Studio 2022, but since it is ASP.NET Framework-4.8 project, it doesn't have: Clean Solution and Clean Project

How are you publishing the application? What happens if you delete the .vs folder and reboot Visual Studio?
